# Python Turtle drawing circle with squares

Tags: python, drawing, draw

Trying to draw this picture using turtle, just stuck on the last bit of drawing square into a circle. [squares to make circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIyYv.png)
so far I've tried just drawing out the points of each individual line but takes way to long with some inconsistencies. What I have so far is

```
def square(side_length):
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(side_length)
        turtle.lt(90)

square (150)

turtle.penup()
        ####New Square###
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(75)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(30)
turtle.right(180)
turtle.right(45)
turtle.pendown()


def square(side_length):
    for i in range(4):
        turtle.fd(side_length)
        turtle.lt(90)
square (150)
```

This draws two squares.  Now I just need to figure out a way to rotate the two squares by, say, 30 degrees clockwise 4 times.  Is there a function I can use to do this, or do I just need to do a lot of math and calculate to draw each individual line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its  name, `turtle.circle` can be used to draw other regular polygons. It also can be used to draw only part of the polygon. Combined with picking the pen up and down, you can easily draw a series of rotated shapes sharing the same center.

For example,

```
 for i in range(19):
     turtle.circle(100, 360, 4)  # draw a square
     turtle.penup()
     # "draw" 10 degrees of the same circle, with the pen up, just to move the pen
     turtle.circle(100, 10, 4)
     turtle.pendown()
```

(The circle is just a polygon with enough sides to approximate a circle. If you don't specify the third argument explicitly, `turtle` picks a sufficiently large value based on the radius.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of the two.  You need to do a little math to find the starting point for each square.  However, once you move the turtle to that point and turn it to the correct heading, your block of statements to draw the four sides will work just fine.

After you draw the last side of a square, the turtle is sitting on the outer circle, facing 45 degrees off a radius to that point.

- Turn the turtle 60 degrees to face across a shallow chord of the circle.
- Move it the appropriate distance to traverse that chord (this is where your math comes in).
- Turn the turtle another 60 degrees.  You are now ready to draw the next square.

Repeat those steps for each added square.